# Hbbtv appdevelopment using Firefox Addon

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon, hbbtv

I am interested to develop hbbtv apps and I am desperate to know how to run and test an full hbbtv application package, in this context a videoplayer having multiple html pages , using Firefox's plugin FireHBBTV. I have pretty much searched for it all over Net but couldn't find one!

Comment: Try http://fraunhoferfokus.github.io/HAT/

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install an http server to serve a files, then it's opening from url address. If you are trying to open first time you can open http://itv.mit-xperts.com/hbbtvtest/ which is like demo page of hbbtv features (not all could work).